# Phone unable to display android application as show in Android Studio when debug

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

After debugging my program and run it on my phone, my phone fail to display exactly what I have design on Android Studio. When using Relative Layout, it display find, now when I switch to Constraint Layout. The problem occur.

Fig 1 is a snapshot of the intended design of my application taken from Android Studio and Fig 2 is the outcome of the application taken from my phone itself

[Intended Design (Fig 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpEZ0.png)
[Outcome image (Fig 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzVVa.png)

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jasonkym.safstrengthcounter.MainActivity"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

<TextView
    android:text="No. of blank files:"
    android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvtNoOfBlankFiles"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="160dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etxNoOfBlankFiles"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="0"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="158dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="117dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvtResults"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="121dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="415dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="No. of people per column:"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvtNoOfPeoplePerRow"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="234dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SAF Strength Counter"
    android:id="@+id/tvtStrengthCounterLabel"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Made by PTE Koh Yi Min Jason"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvtMadebyKohYiMinJason"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="478dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="84dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="No. of people behind:"
    android:layout_width="87dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvtNoOfPeopleBehind"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="23dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="314dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etxNoOfPeopleBehind"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="315dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="118dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="No. of column:"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvtNumberOfRows"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="91dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="407dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="236dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Result:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvtResultsLabel"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="415dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="26dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etxNoOfRows"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="0"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="91dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="115dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etxNoOfPeoplePerRow"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="0"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="234dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="121dp" />


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to take the idea of Relative as well as Constraints layout, then start changing your code. The given link below will help you:

[Differences between ConstraintLayout and RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321448/differences-between-constraintlayout-and-relativelayout/37324703#37324703)

Comment: The screen shot taken in Fig 1 was the intended design of the app in ConstraintLayout. shouldn’t my phone display exactly the same for what I had design on the studio regardless whether it is design in Relative or Constraint Layout? Do I have to add in more line of code for Constraint layout to make it display as shown in the studio? I felt that it is the case as it seem that all of my EditText and TextView are at the top left hand corner of the screen and I have to enter a line of code or two to put the Widget and TextView at the location intended.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is help for you.`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_search_back"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_green"
    android:elevation="@dimen/card_elivation"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/layout_show_response"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_search_back">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_search_for"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_simple_gray">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    style="@style/dialog_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/you_ask_for"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_ask_for"
                    style="@style/dialog_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/view_padding_extra_small"
                    android:text="Ask For"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_darker_gray"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cv_search_for"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_simple_gray">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_result"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    style="@style/dialog_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/result"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_reply"
                    style="@style/dialog_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/view_padding_extra_small"
                    android:text="Result"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_darker_gray" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_img"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_reply"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_show_img"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width_medium"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height_medium"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin_nano"
                        android:background="@mipmap/iv_pasted_icon" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_show_img_icon"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width_medium"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height_medium"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin_nano"
                        android:background="@mipmap/iv_pasted_img" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I have already solve the problem. You need to add constraint when using ConstraintLayout. It will not display as it shown in the Studio without constraint.

May I asked is there a way which I can design an app just in window visual studio where I am designing a form application just drag and drop and do not have to add any constraint? Is there a layout perhaps that enable me to do that?