# How to reduce the layout depth when working with CardViews?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I want to use `CardViews` in my app only for the visual effect.

All `CardViews` will contain very different views, so I cannot really design a good adapter and thus I cannot use a `RecyclerView`.

The result is perfectly clean, but for this I had to nest a lot of `ConstraintLayout`, and so the layout take several seconds to draw itself. (**any advice on how to measure more precisely this delay ?**)

Here the hierarchy of my layout (with 9 `CardViews` and not 2):

```
ConstraintLayout
-Image + text x4
-ScrollView
--ConstraintLayout
---Cardview
----ConstraintLayout
-----text, spinner, button, etc
---Cardview
----ConstraintLayout
-----text, spinner, button, etc
```

You can see the max depth is `ConstraintLayout`>`ScrollView`>`ConstraintLayout`>`CardView`>`ConstraintLayout`, which seems inefficient as hell, as stated in the [Android Optimizing Layout Hierarchies Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html).

**What should I do to flatten my layout ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is fine. And not too deep. The layout is probably not the problem.

Note that it only draws the item on the screen. It does create layouts for the others in the ScrollView, but does not render them. If the drawing was the problem, the scrolling would be slow. You can check that.

Layout might be slow, but I doubt it. There are ways to monitor this though.

Are you loading all images off the UI thread? Nothing on the screen is coming from a server or going through some other complicated (parsing) method?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is my home activity, it only loads the layout and set some onclicklistener that call other activities. The scrolling is not slow and nothing comes from a server (images are just icons from drawables). What are the ways to monitor this ?

Comment: Easies is to start with is not 'layouting' (visibility = gone) 90% of your views. See if it increases speed. If it does then you are right and it's the deep layout. If it does not, then it's elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION 1:

It's okay for RecyclerView to load different views and you can design good adapter for it. Check [A RecyclerView with multiple item types](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e) and [Heterogenous Layouts inside RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView).

### SOLUTION 2:

Considering your hierarchy you can place your cards directly to ScrollView without ConstraintLayout:

```
ConstraintLayout
-Image + text x4
-ScrollView
--Cardview
---ConstraintLayout
----text, spinner, button, etc
--Cardview
---ConstraintLayout
----text, spinner, button, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution: Don't use nested `ConstraintLayout`s, the idea of `ConstraintLayout` is to reduce the amount of nested objects, but there is a performance price for it.

Base on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321448/differences-between-constraintlayout-and-relativelayout#comment72320637_38671211) it's up to 3 times slawer than `RelativeLayout`. And I think that nesting it only increase the problem.

So try replacing `ConstraintLayout` with RelativeLayout and please reply here with the difference in performance, I bet you will see one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try next week but I dont know how to measure the difference.

Comment: @DanChaltiel just print a log before and after setContent view and measure the time between those logs