# Place on the right in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout-gravity

i have to place the seconds TextView and ImageView on the right, but gravity doesn't move. How can I do? Maybe 'gravity' isn't appropriate?
Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/JuventusLogo"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="JUVENTUS"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REAL MADRID"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/RealMadridLogo"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How output should look like?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that using:

### ConstraintLayout

ConstraintLayout allows you to create complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups, like `LinearLayout` in your example). It's similar to `RelativeLayout` in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling. `ConstraintLayout` has much more flexibility and performs better than `RelativeLayout`.

`ConstraintLayout` is available as a support library so you have to add new dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

You can find posts about [differences between ConstraintLayout and RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321448/differences-between-constraintlayout-and-relativelayout) or [How to use constraint (relations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/2386929#2386929)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#F00"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="JUVENTUS"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/first_logo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/first_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="REAL MADRID"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/second_logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/second_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/second_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/second_logo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#00F"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: ConstraintLayout]

---

### LinearLayout

`LinearLayout` is a view group that aligns all children in a single direction (vertically or horizontally like in your example). You can set `android:layout_weight` on individual child views to specify how linear layout divides remaining space amongst the views it contains.

There are many posts about that:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996044/5529263
- [Android Layout Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight)
- [Linear Layout and weight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#F00" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="JUVENTUS" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:text="REAL MADRID" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#00F" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: LinearLayout]

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @Zoe added. Thank you for paying attention.