# Android ScrollView: How to create a scrolling view with static header and footer using constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I am attempting to create a scroll view with a static header and footer like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM98f.png).
Here is the source code for this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="64sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="50.7sp" />

        </ScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnPos"
                android:text="Ok"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="45.7sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="home"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttons"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNeg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="45.7sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="home"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnPos"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttons"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a solved issue using Relative Layout but I have not been able to make it work using Constraint Layout. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zGTn.png) that the scroll view is not constrained above the footer. Here is the source for this layout

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="64sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/divider"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="50sp" />
        </ScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="#000"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttons"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ok"
                android:textSize="45.7sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:onClick="home"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNeg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="45.7sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnPos"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321448/differences-between-constraintlayout-and-relativelayout) the conversion of properties from Relative to Constraint layout is the following

android:layout_above=""  -> app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf=""

and android:layout_below="" -> app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf=""

The repo for a demo application is [here](https://github.com/tmastrom/ScrollView).

The relative layout works but I want to use the latest android layouts for best performance and this should be possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of issues with the layout. One of the purposes of *ConstraintLayout* is that is provides for a flat layout structure. It is not wrong to nest a *ConstraintLayout* inside another *ConstraintLayout*, but it defeats one of the desirable attributes of the layout.

`match_parent` for a view's width or height is discouraged in a *ContraintLayout*. Instead of `match_parent`, use `match_constraints` (`0dp`) with the appropriate constraints set. You have some `match_parent` in your layout. (`match_parent` is OK on the `ConstraintLayout` itself since it will be placed inside of another type of layout.

I went ahead and made some adjustments to the layout below.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="64sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNeg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttons"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="home"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        android:textSize="45.7sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNeg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNeg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="45.7sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnPos" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I agree with what Cheticamp said. The purpose of ConstraintLayout is to have a flat layout structure. And if you are having this issue with this file you post it above you could add a scrollbar to TextView to achieve flat layout structure like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="64sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNeg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttons"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="home"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="45.7sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNeg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNeg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="45.7sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnPos" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The last thing you need to do is to add a movement method to your TextView in code like this:

`((TextView) findViewById(R.id.description)).setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`