# Drag and Drop layouts in android

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

What is the difference between Relative layout and constraint layout in android, can I use both for drag and option design in android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between ConstraintLayout and RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321448/differences-between-constraintlayout-and-relativelayout)

Answer (score 0):

Well relative layout, let you make relation between a child element with another child element or a relation between a child element with the relative layout itself but you won't be able to use drag option, while, in constraint layout it is less responsive but you can use drag option and it will generate x and y co-ordinate for the child elements.